# Solution for continuously running a code part within a MQTT client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, paho

I am trying to send me a message over a mqtt connection and then perform a task on the received messages which are collected in the inbox. The problem is that when I run the code, the messages have not been received yet and the part in the code which shall work on the information in the messages does not run again.

I thought about using a `while True:` loop for that bit, but then the mqtt script won't be reached at all. This does not work.

This might be a very fundamental question, but how can I achieve running the mqtt client continuously and deal with the collected messages at some point later on?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as client

hostname = 'test.mosquitto.org'
topic = "personal/topic"

# receiving the data
inbox = []    

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    msg = msg.payload.decode()
    inbox.append(msg)
    print("Received Message No. %s:    %s" % (len(inbox), msg))    

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connection returned result: " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe(topic)

# this is where I want to perform a task on the message
y = []
X = []
for msg in inbox:
    label, data = msg.split(': ')
    data = data.split(', ')
    y.append(label)
    X.append(data)

# the mqtt part
client = client.Client()
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.connect(hostname)
client.loop_forever()
```

This is the construction using `client.loop_start()`at the end of the script (related to @hardillb's answer):

```
# the mqtt part
client = client.Client()
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.connect(hostname)
client.loop_start()

while True:
    y = []
    X = []
    for msg in inbox:
        label, data = msg.split(': ')
        data = data.split(', ')
        y.append(label)
        X.append(data)

client.disconnect()
client.loop_stop()
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted, it works as expected. Please edit the question to add more details about what you want it to do.

Comment: @hardillb I added the part to the code, where I want to work with the received message. However `y ` and `X` always stay empty

Comment: I think I would put the messages in a `Queue` object an have another Thread trying to `get` an item from the `Queue` as long as there are no items in the `Queue`, `get` blocks the thread

Comment: @user8408080 I have not really looked into threading so far, but I might consider doing it now... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The paho client can start it's network worker on a separate thread by using the `client.loop_start()` function.

You can then start your own processing loop after that, but the `on_message` callback function will run on the client's network worker thread, so if you want to queue up incoming messages to process later you will need to ensure that when you store the messages it is done in a thread safe manner.

Comment: if I replace `client.loop_forever()`with `client.loop_start()` the client will not connect and the `Process finished with exit code 0`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to move your processing for loop after the `client.loop_start()` (and you will also need to wrap the for loop in another loop to deal with the empty array and wait for it to be populated)

Comment: I edited my question above and added the code, I think you suggested. Is this correct? Also with which condition could I handle the loop insted of `True`?